# Cleanest way to re-render component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-reactivity

I have a `Keyboard.vue` component containing many `Key.vue` child component instances (one for each key).

In `Key.vue`, the key is actually a html `<button>` element that can get disabled.

By clicking a certain button in my app, I want to reset keyboard and make all keys enabled again. I thought that setting a `v-if` to `false` then to `true` again (`<keyboard v-if="BooleanValue" />`) would re-render `Keyboard.vue` and all its Key.vue child component instances.

It doesn't. Why not?

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    ...
    <keyboard v-if="!gameIsOver && showKeyboard" />
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    Keyboard
  },
  computed: {
    gameIsOver () {
      return this.$store.state.gameIsOver
    },
    showKeyboard () {
      return this.$store.state.showKeyboard
    }
  }
```

Keyboard.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
    <key class="letter" v-for="(letter) in letters" :key="letter" :letter="letter" />
  </section>
</template>
```

Key.vue

```
<template>
  <button :disabled="disabled" @click="checkLetter(letter)">
    {{ letter }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data () {
    return {
      disabled: false
    }
  }
```

My button resetting keyboard triggers:

```
this.$store.commit('SET_KEYBOARD_VISIBILITY', false)
this.$store.commit('SET_KEYBOARD_VISIBILITY', true)
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: OK, I just edited the question

Comment: It should automatically rerender the component. The fact that it does not likely means your variable is not reactive, or overwritten in such a way that it cannot be detected. Since your variable `disabled` in Key.vue comes out of nowhere, I can't really check where your variable comes from, or how it is modified.

Comment: As for your other question: Rerendering only happens on the next tick. If you modify a variable twice within a tick, it will only use the last value for the next rerender

Comment: @Sumurai8 I've set the variable back to `true` in the next tick and now it works, thanks! I think it might be worth it that you make an answer (I'll accept it) because I suspect many people don't know this.

Comment: Your `keyboard` component only has that code? What about its props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is to have the disabled state somewhere where you can reset it, because re-rendering your component to reset it is making use of a side-effect of destroying and re-creating your components. It makes it hard for someone to figure out *why* the buttons are enabled again, because there is no code changing the `disabled` variable to `false` anywhere that is being called when you rerender.

That said, you see your current behaviour because Vue aggregates all changes of the current "tick", and only rerenders at the end of that tick. That means if you set your variable to false, then to true, it will only use the last value.

```
// Nothing happens
this.showSomething = false
this.showSomething = true
```

To force it to re-render, you can use the trick Amitha shows, using key. Since Vue will use an instance per key value, changing the key will destroy the old one and create a new one. Alternatively, you can use `this.$nextTick(() => { ... })` to force some of your code to run on the next tick.

```
// Destroy all the things
this.showSomething = false
this.$nextTick(() => {
  // Okay, now that everything is destroyed, lets build it up again
  this.showSomething = true
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited again to show that `disabled` is a regular data variable. I agree with your answer's first sentence however how can I set `disabled` to `false` in all Key component instances at once?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question first, the cleanest way to re-render a Vue component or any element is to bind it's `key` attribute to something reactive that will control the re-renders, whenever the key value changes it will trigger a re-render.

To make such a unique key per render, I would probably use an incremented number and whenever I would like to re-render I would increment it.

```
<template>
<div>
  <div :key="renderKey">
  </div>
</div>
</template.

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    renderKey: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    reRender() {
       this.renderKey++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now as for why toggling `v-if` didn't work: Toggling a reactive property between true and false doesn't necessarily trigger 2 re-renders because Vue has an async update queue which applies DOM changes in patches in certain time frames, not per individual update. This why Vue is so fast and efficient.

So you trigger `disabled` to `false`, then to `true`. The renderer will decide not to update the DOM because the final value has not changed from the last time, the timing is about 16ms If I recall correctly. So you could make that work by waiting more than 16ms between toggling your prop between `true` and `false`, I say "could" but not "should".

Comment: what about multiple component?

Comment: You could either wrap your components in a `div` and assign your reactive `:key` prop to that `div`. Or better yet, reuse your reactive prop for multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try to set a :key for keyboard like below

```
<keyboard v-if="!gameIsOver && showKeyboard" :key="increment" />
```

"increment": local component property

and increase the "increment" property value by one when you need to re-render view. use the vuex store property to sync with local "increment" property.

how to sync vuex value changes with local property: add a "watcher" to watch the vuex store property changes and assigned that change to the local "increment" property which we setted as the "key" for keyboard